# MySQL upgrade (5.5 to 5.7)

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I upgraded my MySQL version from 5.5 to 5.7 and in phpmyadmin I get this error message. I tried to reinstall and reconfigure it but I have still this problem. Can you help me? I am using Linux Mint. Thank you

[image]

Comment: Read about [`mysql_upgrade`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql-upgrade.html). It is a tool that has to be executed after the MySQL server software is upgraded. It upgrades the databases.

Comment: this is working for me. using this https://askubuntu.com/questions/750498/mysql-5-5-update-to-mysql-5-7

Answer (score 2):

It takes two steps.  You must upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 and run mysql_upgrade, then do 5.6 to 5.7.

Answer (score 2):

When you are upgrading best practice is to upgrade to the next available version i.e just upgrade from 5.5 to 5.6 using mysql_upgrade , you can do in place upgrade or you can take entire database dump and install a new service and restore the backed up database there.
and once you move to 5.6 upgrade it to 5.7 version.